# write/read string in a TTree (cern root)

Tags: c++, string, tree, root-framework

after saving a string into a TTree

```
std::string fProjNameIn,  fProjNameOut;
TTree *tTShowerHeader;
tTShowerHeader = new TTree("tTShowerHeader","Parameters of the Shower");
tTShowerHeader->Branch("fProjName",&fProjNameIn);
tTShowerHeader->Fill();
```

I'm trying to do the following

```
fProjNameOut = (std::string) tTShowerHeader->GetBranch("fProjName");
```

which does not compile, though

```
std::cout << tTShowerHeader->GetBranch("fProjName")->GetClassName() << std::endl;
```

tells me, this Branch is of type `string`

is there a standard way to read a std::string from a root tree?

Comment: What is the type of `tTShowerHeader` ?

Comment: -1: I have absolutely zero idea what TTree is and still am able to tell at first sight it can't compile and why, so I suspect a little more careful reading of documentation would be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this took a while but I figured out how to get the information from the tree. You cannot directly return the information, it can only be returned through the variable it was given in.

```
std::string fProjNameIn,  fProjNameOut;
TTree *tTShowerHeader;

fProjnameIn = "Jones";
tTShowerHeader = new TTree("tTShowerHeader","Parameters of the Shower");
tTShowerHeader->Branch("fProjName",&fProjNameIn);
tTShowerHeader->Fill();//at this point the name "Jones" is stored in the Tree

fProjNameIn = 0;//VERY IMPORTANT TO DO (or so I read)
tTShowerHeader->GetBranch("fProjName")->GetEntries();//will return the # of entries
tTShowerHeader->GetBranch("fProjName")->GetEntry(0);//return the first entry
//At this point fProjNameIn is once again equal to "Jones"
```

In root the TTree class stores the address to the varriable used for input into it. Using GetEntry() will fill the same variable with the information stored in the TTree.
You can also use tTShowerHeader->Print() to display the number of entires for each branch.

Comment: -1: Never ever suggest C style cast in C++. Most of the time don't suggest *any* cast in C++. C++ code that needs casts is usually either plain wrong or at least too clever for it's own good.

Comment: Alright, thanks (I was just using the code from the question verbatum). Could you by any chance tell me how you should do the casting in C++?

Comment: @ad1dicburn: Well written C++ code should do without casts, only using implicit ones and the "function-style" cast, which is really a request to construct a temporary. But if you occasionally need other, there are `static_cast` (for related pointers and references), `dynamic_cast` (for runtime checking of polymorphic classes), `const_cast` (removes CV-qualification) and `reinterpret_cast` (for unrelated pointers). Of course you should only ever need `const_cast` to work around bad interface and `reinterpret_cast` will probably invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: one gets the name specified for Branch, but not the contents of the string

Comment: I did a little digging and found how to answer the question. use [GetEntry()](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html#TTree:GetEntry)

Comment: Unfortunately, ROOT is not all "well written C++ code" :-). Sometimes, C style casts are idiomatic in ROOT, such as ``TTree* tree = (TTree*) gDirectory->Get("myTree");``. Using a ``static_cast`` would confuse my colleagues who have to read the code to hell.

Answer (score 3):

The solution follows below.

Imagine you have a ROOT file and you want to save an std::string to it.

```
TTree * a_tree = new TTree("a_tree_name");
std::string a_string("blah");
a_tree->Branch("str_branch_name", &a_string); // at this point, you've saved "blah" into a branch as an std::string
```

To access it:

```
TTree * some_tree = (TTree*)some_file->Get("a_tree_name");
std::string * some_str_pt = new std::string(); 
some_tree->SetBranchAddress("str_branch_name", &some_str_pt);

some_tree->GetEntry(0);
```

To print to standard output:

```
std::cout << some_str_pt->c_str() << std::endl;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `tTShowerHeader->GetBranch("fProjName")`**->** and it compiles. That means that return type of `tTShowerHeader->GetBranch()` is a **pointer**.

Moreover, you are calling `GetClassName()` on that pointer and it compiles, so it's a pointer to a class type.

Even more, the `std::string` does **not** have a `GetClassName()` method, so it's **not** a `std::string*`. Indeed, it [seems it is `TBranch *`](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html). You must [find appropriate method that will give you the text](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TBranch.html).

PS: Unlearn to use C-style cast in C++. C-style cast is **evil**, because it will do different things depending on what the type happens to be. Use the restricted `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast` or function-style casts instead (and `reinterpret_cast` if you really need that, but that should be extremely rare).

Comment: I see your point. worked out how to store a fixed size char string instead - as it seems, TTree can only store c-type objects.

`fXY = (TH2D*)rootfile->Get("XY");` is a common technique in root, so I tried to cast a standard type admittedly instead of a root-class.